# How to make cron use UTC for one crontab only

Tags: cron, timezone

I need to have the rules in one crontab processed using UTC -- that is, the times and day rollovers should be considered as if the computer is in UTC-0, while all other crontabs on the system are processed using the normal local timezone.

Googles haven't turned up anything useful.  Generally, they've sent me to how to configure cron to use UTC.  But I am *not* trying to change cron to use UTC generally -- only for just this one crontab.

Changing the installed implementation of cron is not an option for me, as I do not have administrative control over the machine.  I can ask for it to be changed; and after going through miles of security bureaucracy and crossing 10 different people's desks, the request might be approved, but probably not.

Any suggestions much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: That may not be possible. But if, for example, you want to run a command at 00:00 UTC, you could run it every hour and have the command itself check the current UTC time. Would that meet your requirements?

Comment: In theory -- but it's a really long crontab, with heterogenous jobs (binaries, python scripts, bash scripts, etc.), each with different recurrence conditions (times/frequencies) over the course of a day.  Presumably each could get a wrapper that does such comparisons; but it'd be a lot of work.

Comment: You could write a single short shell script that takes the required UTC time and the command to invoke as arguments, then invoke it from crontab as `/path/to/wrapper.sh 00:00 command args...`. Also, if a cron job is scheduled for the top of the hour, be prepared for it to be invoked at least a few seconds later.

Comment: Oof.  I can see how that would work; but almost nothing in there is scheduled for a specific time, but rather for different frequencies/cadences.  Those could be expanded out into multiple entries, of course, but then the crontab goes from being really long to really really long . . .

Comment: Can you add more information to your question about how you want the jobs to be scheduled? A good description would be "these crontab entries" (followed by actual crontab entries) "but scheduled in UTC rather than local time". I have a few vague ideas (run crontab in a virtual machine with UTC as its default time zone, write a tool that translates a UTC-based crontab to a localtime-based crontab and rebuild the crontab on DST transitions), but more details would help. Question: If you're concerned about frequencies/cadences, why does the time zone matter?